# PhoneGap Ajax API Request is not responding

Tags: ajax, api, codeigniter, phonegap

I am making an AJAX API request from a PhoneGap project to a web server. But the server is not responding. 
Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $("#submit").click(function(){ 
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val(); 

        var baseURL='http://mydomainname.com/myWebProject/'; 
        $.ajax({
            url:baseURL+'CustomerAuth/loginCheck',
            method:"GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {email:email, password:password},
            success:function(data){
                alert("style");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My web project is CodeIgniter 3x
I have disabled CSRF protection
I have added these code in config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://multidimensionsystems.com" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

And here is the code of my method of web project:

```
public function loginCheck() {
   echo "success";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try to access api from post man, or any REST api client

Comment: Thank you, I have made a REST api and it is working, but now different issue raised. It is now working when i run from PC, when I run from mobile, but when i am building an API and running from mobile by after installing, it is not working, even no error is showing.